# Debug single javascript file in “Visual Studio Code”

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to debug a single javascript file step by step without launching a node server?

For example seed files by knex.

Node is definitely needed, but I do not know how to start the VSC debugger with only the file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Just add `launch.json` and give your `file_name`. and start
  debugging.

  For example, If your `file_name` is `index.js`. create a folder
  called `.vscode` and inside this folder create `launch.json`, structure looks like this:

  ```
                main_folder
                     |___ index.js
                     |___ .vscode
                             |___ launch.json
  ```

  and provide path as below in `launch.json`:

  ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
         "configurations": [
           {
             "type": "node",
             "request": "launch",
             "name": "Launch Current Opened File",
             "program": "${file}"
           }
         ]
    }
  ```
- The second option is to create a `package.json` and give your file an entry point. when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, `vscode` will consider this file as starting point.

  ```
                   main_folder
                       |___ index.js
                       |___ package.json
  ```

  you can create `package.json` manually or can create it using `npm init`, This will ask you a bunch of questions, and then write a `package.json` for you.

  ```
   {
     "name": "application_name",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     "description": "for single page debugging",
     "main": "index.js",
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC"
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. So basically I have always to provide the path to the single js file. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 14):

To launch(debug) currently opened/active *.js file, you should have the following configuration in your `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Current Opened File",
        "program": "${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To have a global way to debug any file search for "Launch" in the VS Code settings. Find this text: "Global debug launch configuration. Should be used as an alternative to 'launch.json' that is shared across workspace". Press "Edit in settings.json" and add "configurations" posted above under the field "launch"

Answer (score 4):

You can run your current file in a Node environment without creating a launch.json.

With the file you want to debug open, go to the debugger panel, click the green arrow and choose Node as your environment.

[From the folks at VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/debugging)

Comment: This does not work. My debugger panel has no green arrow.

Answer (score 2):

To help with any confusion, your debug options depend on how your workspace is setup:

1. If you have not created a `launch.json` file, you will see the following options in the debug panel. Clicking `Run and Debug` will debug the currently active file.

   [image]
2. If you have a `package.json` file, you will still see the same view shown above; however, VSCode will first try to debug the file name you have specified in the `main` attribute of your `package.json`. If it does not find that file, it will then debug the currently active file. So, for instance, if my `package.json` shows `index.js` as my `main` file, then VSCode will always run that file in the debugger if it can find it instead of your currently active file.
3. Finally, you can be more explicit by adding configurations to `launch.json`. When you do this you can then choose which file to debug from the drop-down. In my environment, I add an option to be able to run the currently active file (the first entry in the JSON below), as well as, any other files I want to access quickly (the second entry in the JSON below). Now, the dropdown will show these options to choose from.

   ```
   {
       // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
       // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
       // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "node",
               "request": "launch",
               "name": "Debug this file",
               "program": "${file}",
               "skipFiles": [
                   "<node_internals>/**"
               ]
           },
           {
               "type": "node",
               "request": "launch",
               "name": "Debug testing.js",
               "program": "${workspaceFolder}/testing.js",
               "skipFiles": [
                   "<node_internals>/**"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   [image]

For more details, check-out [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way for me...
Right-click on the file in VS file explorer.
Click "open in Terminal".
Then in terminal type `node myFile.js`