# VSCode JavaScript debug settings of specific file

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, settings

I wanted to test debugging a JS file in this particular workspace, so I pressed F5 then the "Select debugger" menu dropped down, and then I chose one of them.
[image: select debugger drop down menu]
Now, no matter what I do, I can't manage to reset this setting.
What I want is to make this menu drop down again when I press F5.

I should point out that:

- choosing a debugger in this case is NOT generating a launch.json file;
- I can create it, though, ("create a launch.json file" at the "Run and Debug" window) and then delete it, but it doesn't change anything;
- I can even change the debugger, but never reset this functionality as I want (i.e. make the drop down menu appear instead of jumping straight to debugging when pressing F5);

The weird part is that it seems like a file/workspace specific configuration, because new JS files in this same workspace, JS files in other workspaces, and even opening this problematic file alone do behave as I wish.
So I guess this isn't a User neither a Workspace setting, but an association of that specific file with some debugger.

When working with C++ files, for example, choosing a specific compiler from that menu would create a launch.json as expected, which if deleted would eliminate previous debugging settings(as expected...). This is just not happening with JS.

[Update]
This is showing in the debug console when I press F5:

```
(node:10464) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug single javascript file in “Visual Studio Code”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167457/debug-single-javascript-file-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it doesn't. There is no ```launch.json``` or ```package.json``` files in this case. They just haven't been created for whatever reason. All I'm trying to do is undo the association between this JS file and the debugger I've chosen randomly. If I press the F5 key in order to debug this file, it opens a debugger automatically, and I'm trying to revert that.